# Does Weka setClassIndex and setAttributeIndices start attribute from different rage?

Tags: classification, weka

I am using WEKA for classification. I am using two function,  "setClassIndex"  and "setAttributeIndices". My dataset have two attributes, class and one more attribute.  Following are some instances in my database:

```
@relation sms_test
@attribute spamclass {spam,ham}
@attribute mes String
@data
ham,'Go until jurong point'
ham,'Ok lar...'
spam,'Free entry in 2 a wkly'
```

Following is part of my code.

```
        trainData.setClassIndex(0);

        filter = new StringToWordVector();
        filter.setAttributeIndices("2");
```

This code is running fine. But when I set, train.setClassIndex ("**1**")  or filter.setAttributeIndices("**1**") , my code stops running. Do setClassIndex function take argument starting from 0 and setAttributeIndices takes argument starting from 1? How do we identify which WEKA function starts counting from 0 or 1?

Answer (score 0):

*Do setClassIndex function take argument starting from 0*

Yes, index starts with 0.

*and setAttributeIndices takes argument starting from 1?*

Yes, indices start from 1

Source: http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable